# d3.js moving time axis quickly, minimal redraw?

Tags: time, d3.js, transition

One of Mike Bostock's D3.js examples for path transitions shows a chart with time along the X axis, and data appearing and shifting left, along with the axis (think of "monitor" displays like Task Manager on Windows). I'm trying to do that same thing, having time moving smoothly to the left. But with four graphs (all the same time scale).

The problem: Mike re-calls the time-axis generator on each tick. At this point that's the most expensive part of the graph drawing, around 90% of the time spent. Anybody have any ideas how to do the scrolling left some other way that doesn't require that redraw every time? I thought of trying to pre-create an axis, then using panning and clipping to show only the relevant parts, but wanted to see if anybody else had a better (i.e. faster) solution, or knows of an example somewhere.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: I think pre-creating the time-axis and then just shifting the SVG viewport should be best performancewise.

Comment: any ideas on how that might interact with zoom & pan?

Answer (score 1):

There is a D3 plug-in framework called [Cubism](http://square.github.io/cubism/) that seems designed to do exactly what you're describing. And since it builds on D3 you will still be able to customize things.

However, if you're looking to do this yourself in D3, you might want to check out the approach they use, which is based on using HTML5 Canvas to shift the existing visualization to the left rather than re-rendering it:

https://github.com/square/cubism/blob/master/src/horizon.js